# form does not get submitted in chrome and Firefox also has issue with form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, onclick, form-submit

I am having issues submitting the form in chrome.

```
<form id="litesignup" name="litesignup" method="post" action="/social/signup_lite.jsp">
<input type="hidden" name="submission" value="done" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="actionName" value="ordermobilepref" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="successPage" value="<%= successPage %>" />
<input type="hidden" name="terms" value="true" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="LITESIGNUP" value="true" />

<table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="8">

:
:
:
:
<tr>
<td style="padding-top: 10px;"><a onclick="document.litesignup.submit();"  class="butText" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;">
                        <input type="submit" id="signupbtn" maxlength="25" size="19" value="Create Account"> </a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

sample code is above. When I test it in localhost it works fine in all the browsers. But in dev environment, only IE works fine. Chrome does not submit the form and Firefox ends up showing the message -"This document you requested is moved temporarily. Its now at - "http://dev4....../.../..."

Please help me understand  what could be happening in different environments and why so strange behavior. Also provide a resolution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code and explanation isn't sufficient. It is totally not clear and mentioned what your "**document.litesignup.submit()**"-method does. Also it's not clear, if it's either a JavaScript error, or Backend-Error - because it seems, that your Backend will try to rediret to "**<%= successPage %>**" - but what's in this variable? What's the logic?

Comment: show the **document.litesignup.submit()** function

Comment: Are you telling your function what to actually submit? Did you try `document.getElementById('litesignup').submit();`

Comment: @SebastianG.Marinescu this form is used to create account for new users. Basically a sign up form. I made use of the existing code and havent changed anything much. That page also has the same onclick="" code for the submit. as i said, in the localhost the same form works fine as expected creates new user account when clicked on the submit button.

Comment: @Invent-Animate i tried using getElementById, still the form does not submit. Even the console shows no error.